# Modular exponentiation twice over

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What is a general way to calculate something like $2147089412^{1147068432^{647017654}}\pmod m$?  It looks like modular exponentiation, but how do you reduce the highest part properly?

Note: $m$ is prime

**Result:**

Case 1: Where $\text{left}\equiv 0\pmod m$, the result is either $1$ ($\text{mid}=0, \text{right} > 0$) or $0$

Case 2: otherwise result is modular power(left, modular power(mid, right, $m-1$), $m$)

Thank you,
Derek

Comment: If you an find an $n$ so $2147089412^n = 1 (\mod m)$, start by calculating $1147068432^{647017654} (\mod n)$

Comment: Such an $n$ can be found by Euler's generalization of Fermat's Little Theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euler's generalization of Fermat's Little Theorem tells us that:

$$ a^b \equiv a^c \mod m $$

when $a$ coprime to $m$ when $b \equiv c \mod \phi(m)$, where $\phi(m)$ counts the number of residues $1 \le k \le m$ that are coprime to $m$ (aka Euler's phi function).

So you would begin by reducing the exponent modulo $\phi(m)$, before moving on to the reduction of the "outer" problem modulo $m$.  Using binary exponentiation can help, of course.

Comment: In the non-coprime case, additionally use the Chinese Remainder Thorem, and usually the exponent of any commmon prime factor of $a$ and $m$ will occur in $a^b$ in trivially much higher power than in $m$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Excellent point.  Since we don't know $m$, I didn't think to press the analysis further.  However $\phi(m)$ will certainly be even (in any nontrivial calculation), so reducing the nested exponent mod $\phi(m)$ will necessarily involve separating out the GCD$(1147068432,\phi(m))$ as you outline (and quite possibly $m$ will likewise have common factors with the base $2147089412$).